# Angular 11 if condition fails

Tags: angular

I have an error in angular code after upgrading from angular 7 to 11, which occurs only when `ng build --prod`. But when running from `ng serve --port 4200` it works as expected without any cause of error.

Below is the array of length 1

```
if(array != null) {
array.forEach(arr => {
   if(arr.status === 'fail') {
      some code...
   }
})
}
```

For the above code if `arr.status === 'fail'` it executes the code inside the if block.
But the `arr.status` executed to `'success'` in this scenario. Even though the value is success the execution enters the if block.

So i changed the code as below to test it

```
if(array != null) {
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       if(array[i].status === 'fail') {
          some code...
       }
    }
    }
```

In this scenario what happens is, the value of `i becomes 1` after iteration. In such case it shouldn't enter the if block but it enters the if block and the code breaks.

Is there any criteria I need to follow on building angular 11 production build or did I make any
error in writing the code.

Comment: Can you add a a `console.log(arr)` before your if condition in the first example ? By the way, your second example can't work, you need to change `arr` with `array`. You can add a `console.log(array)` in your second example also.

Comment: Try to add a breakpoint and see why it stops there.

Comment: @Florian Yes i added console.log(arr) it prints the status success

Comment: @Shahar I checked that as well. It seems like only ng build --prod has this issue but ng serve --port 4200 working as expected

Comment: @ramvinoth ok now, can you add a `console.log('inside if loop')` in your if condition ?

Comment: @Florian It is undefined

Comment: hmm, what is undefined ? You either have a print in your console or you dont, but the `console.log('inside if loop')` can't print undefined

Comment: The arr value is undefined.. Thats the problem. Even the value is undefined it enter the if block.

Comment: @ramvinoth add the `console.log('inside if loop')` and tell me if u have a print "inside if loop". We're not looking for `arr` value here, we want to ensure that you go inside this portion of code which seems very unlikely to me

Comment: @ramvinoth obviously something changes when you switch between dev and prod builds. Try to see when or where is `array` generated and can this value be different in prod and in dev builds. I would start by searching all occurrences for it.

Comment: Finally after setting "optimization": false under production configuration in angular.json solve the issue. The issue is not specific to conditions but specific to angular build issue. Thanks.